# Is there a limit to the number of tier prices of a product?

Tags: product, price, tierprice, save

I am using Magento **1.9.2.0**.
I have many (35) customer groups because I want to set different discounts for each group. For each customer group there are a number of tier prices for a product. And here lies the problem:

1. **You can't add more than 197 tier prices**. They simply aren't saved. There is no error message or a warning. I created over 200 tier prices for different customer groups but after the product was altered and saved all tier prices above 197 were lost.
2. Also it isn't possible to edit the category or the meta tags with this many tier prices. The message with "product has been saved" appears but the entered values for the meta tags are lost. Only after I delete some tier prices to only have about 190, I can save changes in the meta tags and the category.

   - Has anybody expiriences the same issue?
   - What is the reason for this?
   - Does anybody know a workaround to add more tier prices?

I opened a [ticket](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/601) in the Magento bug tracking system but no reply as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the issue is not with the code.
Theoretically it supports an infinite number of tierprices.
I had issues in the past with submitting large forms because of the `max_input_vars` value from `php.ini`. Try increasing that value.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was indeed the cause of the problem.